# How to set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in .bash_profile?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have added

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
```

in .bash_profile.

But when I echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in Terminal, It is showing blank line.

Comment: Did you export the variable in your bash_profile?  Copy the exact line from your script into your question.

Comment: Even after adding export also, It is not working

Comment: Are you sure your file is `bash_profile` and not `.bash_profile`?  Also, did you `source` your script before trying to `echo` the variable?

Comment: My bad, It is .bash_profile. Corrected the question

Comment: Try also a file named .bashrc (dot-bashrc) in your home directory.

Comment: @linuxfan, traditionally, `.bashrc` is supposed to be used for variables that _aren't_ exported; the idea of `.bash_profile` is that it's run only once (in the "login shell" that's first created when a user starts a new session) to perform settings that child processes will inherit through the environment, whereas `.bashrc` is run for each and every interactive shell to do configuration that won't be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You should export variable into bash_profile.
Access your home directory and edit file.

```
cd ~
sudo vim .bash_profile
```

Add your export into file.

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
```

Press esc, and type wq, to write and quit from editor mode.
Reload terminal settings using source command.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now try print your value:

```
echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
```

Comment: Why are you instructing the OP to do something they claim they already did?

Comment: (also, one shouldn't use `sudo` to edit one's own dotfiles: they're supposed to be owned by the current user; using `sudo` can potentially cause them to be owned by root, if one ends up creating a file where it didn't previously exist, or if one's editor uses a create-and-rename pattern that doesn't use `chown` or `chmod` to force permissions to match).

Comment: Why I can't reply? 
About the sudo I agree, but if he using in his local machine it's not a problem.

Have a great day.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set like this.`export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.vendor=Sun\ Microsystems\ Inc\.`

Comment: This does _exactly_ the same thing as the OP's original code; `"hello world"` and `hello\ world` evaluate to precisely the same string in shell. You can test this: `if [ JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc." = JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.vendor=Sun\ Microsystems\ Inc\. ]; then echo "Identical"; fi`. The only difference is that this version is slightly more version-specific because the meaning of `\.` is unspecified (`.` characters don't need to be backslash-quoted).